# Could I ask a question regarding hardware?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I have a small budget to build a computer that I plan on using for scientific computing purposes (I write and run 32-bit Python/C simulations). However, I am completely out of the loop when it comes to hardware, and I wonder if it would be appropriate to ask what kind of processors and other do-dads I should be considering when I gather the parts for such a computer.

Appropriate question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, we have had hardware questions in the past, and welcome additional hardware questions, so long as they clearly mention the types of computational science tasks that are to be targeted by the hardware.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a tag purpose built for hardware questions. So, for my question I simply used the "simulation" tag. Are there any others you'd recommend?